# How i make a DependencyProperty from a template child to be accessed from the parent?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

Style is like that:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:Setup}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:Setup}">
                <CheckBox x:Name="PART_CheckBox"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And i want to make a property for Setup called 'IsChecked' but to check the CheckBox control if is checked. Only the Get, not Set.

```
public class Setup : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCheckedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsChecked", typeof(bool), typeof(Setup), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    private CheckBox _CheckBox = null;

    // -[ Constructor:

    public Setup() : base()
    {

    }

    static Setup()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Setup), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Setup)));
    }

    // -[ Template:

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _CheckBox = (CheckBox) Template.FindName("PART_CheckBox", this);
        _CheckBox.Unchecked += _CheckBox_Unchecked;
        _CheckBox.Checked += _CheckBox_Unchecked;
        _CheckBox.Indeterminate += _CheckBox_Unchecked;
    }

    private void _CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsChecked = _CheckBox.IsChecked == true;
    }

    // -[ Property:

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return (bool) GetValue(IsCheckedProperty); }
        private set { SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Is other alternative to capture the child IsChecked to parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A template binding only works oneway to display values stored but does not allow you to set them
If you want to set them you need a normal binding which is twoway but you have to tell it to connect to the templated parent:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type c:Setup}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:Setup}">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked , RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I try this. But when the CheckBox changes the state, the parent IsChecked is not modified. ------------------------__ I need like: Child -> Parent, not parent -> Child.

Comment: Maybe a CodeBehind. Not the style.

Comment: @And-RoMarian this is a task XAML is totally capable of doing no need for code logic!

Comment: You are binding the TemplatedParent in CheckBox. But if you Unchecked the CheckBox, The TemplatedParent is still Checked. Need to capture the IsChecked from CheckBox and to set to TemplateParent. I don't know a right way.

Comment: try the code in my edited answer it works fine no need to use events

Comment: what do you mean how does this work? that's data binding? Wasnt you looking for a solution like this?

Comment: Yes, this is. I found the response for Binding. Its working with Two Ways.